# Did Denzel Washington say this quote claiming people who criticize are doing less than you?

Tags: quotes

The [B2B Revenue Leadership Show](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/the-b2b-revenue-leadership-show_sales-activity-6892384355365249024-xGuY) shared a post with a quote about criticism allegedly said by Denzel Washington. Was this said by Denzel Washington?

Quote and image below

> You'll never be criticized by someone who is doing more than you. You'll always be criticized by someone who is doing less. Remember that.

[image: Image with quote]

Comment: It's certainly widely shared on quotation and positivity sites in the last few years, but I can't find any kind of authoritative source via Google. The earliest I found was quoted without attribution in December 2018 [on some person's Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/teambossbabe/photos/youll-never-be-criticized-by-someone-doing-more-than-you-youll-only-be-criticize/2146988672006501/).

Comment: I looked on Twitter and found it attributed to nearly everyone you can imagine, including [Mahatma Gandhi in what I think is Portuguese](https://twitter.com/CamiciSonia/status/1484886934681968641)!